# VBA equivalent to Save As Picture in PPT

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to use vba to save grouped shapes as an image in powerpoint. The "save as picture" function that you can use by right clicking on the group produces high quality images. My attempt to recreate the right-click function produces blurry, low quality images. Is there a way to exactly recreate the right click save as picture instead of export?

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Select
Call ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Export( _
"C:\myloction.png", _
ppShapeFormatPNG)
```

Comment: I'm curious too why do the right click option gives you different resolution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add optional scaleheight/scalewidth parameters after the ppShapeFormat parameter. The results seem almost random, I don't know exactly what the parms are supposed to relate to, but the bigger the number you feed it, the higher the rez of the exported image.

Comment: I've tried to understand the relation between numbers and scale but I couldn't. The last parameter seems useless.

Comment: This worked! The bigger the number I gave it, the clearer the image got.  'Call ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Export( _
    strpath, ppShapeFormatPNG, 3072, 2304, ppScaleToFit)' matched the quality of the right click-> save as option.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  3072 is a magic number in PPT; it's the highest number of pixels that you can use with Slide.Export when exporting full images, at least in versions prior to 2013 or so.  Now if only the Kozmic Lightbulb would go on above and reveal the *meaning* of this tantalizing bit of coincidence ...  ;-)